# VBA Array Function - Return Array from Range without Blanks

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am struggling with a basic problem in VBA and would appreciate some help. I want to define a function which returns an array from a range without blanks, as shown below:

[image]

So when I call the function in the European Option cell, the function should return an array without any blanks, like on the right hand side.

This is the code I have so far:

```
   Function portfolioX(N)
   Dim MyArray(3)
   Dim i As Integer
   counter = 1
    For i = 1 To N
        If IsEmpty(i) Then
            Next i
        Else
            portfolio = MyArray
            MyArray (counter)
            counter = counter + 1
            Next i
        End If
End Function
```

I am a newbie to VBA, so this could be completely wrong. Thanks!

Comment: The first thing to learn when learning VBA is the distinction between Subroutines and Functions.  When you want something to simply add an appropriate value to a single cell, use a function.  When you want to do any other form of datasheet manipulation, you need to use a subroutine.  Thus, I am unsure of exactly what you are hoping the code will do for you.  If you can clarify a little bit, I'll be happy to help

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. Can you elaborate more? Please include what data should be evaluated, how you want it evaluated, and the expected result.

Comment: Hi @RGA thank you for your help! As shown in the picture above, I want a function which takes a range as input (A1:A13 for instance). The function should output an array (A18:A21 above) with the content of the range, whereby blanks should not be considered. So if the function is called on the range in the picture (shown in green) the output should be the cells on the right hand side (shown in white in the picture). Was that clearer?

Comment: Think you are still confusing Functions and Subs, but from what you've described I believe you want a sub that will take a given range and then paste only the values from the cells that are not blank, removing the blank space in between.  Is that correct?

Comment: Correct! Sorry for being confusing!

Answer (score 0):

If statement and loop are blocks of code. You can not interlace blocks of code.

```
Function portfolioX(N)

    For i = 1 To N ' Block 1 starts
        If IsEmpty(i) Then ' Block 2 starts
        Next i 'Block 1 can't loop back because Block 2 has't closed
    Else
        portfolio = MyArray
        MyArray (counter)
        counter = counter + 1
    Next i 'Block 1 can't loop back because Block 2 has't closed
    End If ' Block 2

End Function
```

When coding it is code practice to write the complete loop structure then fill in the inner code.
I would write the For loop first

```
For i = 1 to N

next i
```

Next comes the If block

```
For i = 1 To N
    If IsEmpty(i) Then

    End If
Next i
```

And finally

```
Function portfolioX(N)
    Dim MyArray(3)
    Dim i As Integer
    counter = 1
    For i = 1 To N ' Block 1 Starts
        If IsEmpty(i) Then Block 2 Starts
            portfolio = MyArray
            MyArray (counter)
            counter = counter + 1
        End If ' Block 2 Closes
    Next i 'If the Loop Condition is meet, Block 1 Closes, else i is incremented and the loop starts over
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Given what you are asking for, I've written a quick sub that will take whatever range you have highlighted and paste the values with the blank cells removed at the end of the row.  Hopefully this can give you a start towards what you are hoping to accomplish.

```
Sub RemoveBlanks()

Dim OriginalRange As Range, WorkCell As Range, PasteCol As Integer
Set OriginalRange = Selection.Rows(1) 'Ensures only one row of data is selected
PasteCol = Range(Cells(OriginalRange.Row, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 2).Address).End(xlToLeft)
For Each WorkCell In OriginalRange
    If Not IsEmpty(WorkCell) Then
        Cells(OriginalRange.Row, PasteCol).Value = WorkCell.Value
        PasteCol = PasteCol + 1
Next WorkCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and comments in that thread, I understand that you wish to take a given range (supplied to the procedure) and print all non-empty values to some range starting on the same row in column R (the 18th column).

In a comment, you supply the ranges `A1:A13` and `A18:A21`, but those do not match with your screenshot. I assume you meant row 1 (or some arbitrary row), columns 1 to 13 and columns 18 to 21.

Here is a solution to that problem:

```
Sub arrayPaster(rng As Range)
    Dim s() As Variant, r() As Variant, j As Integer

    ReDim r(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    s = rng.Value
    j = 1

    For i = 1 To UBound(s, 2)
        If s(1, i) <> "" Then
            ReDim Preserve r(1 To 1, 1 To j)
            r(1, j) = s(1, i)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i

    Range("R" & rng.Row).Resize(1, UBound(r, 2)).Value = r
End Sub
```